# Strapi populate query string

Tags: node.js, strapi

Exists another or most elegancy way to do this query ?

i think this way weird :  repeting populate

```
 http://localhost:1337/api/produto?populate=brands&populate=categories&populate=image
```

i try http://localhost:1337/api/produto?populate=brands&categories&image

not works .

Comment: This is defined by the API and so you can't do anything about it as it's something on Strapi's end that is out of your control. Besides, repeating is actually quite a normal way of expressing that a given query string key has multiple values (there are many ways, but the only people who decide what to use are the devs at Strapi).